# javascript custom dialog box with delay

Tags: javascript

I want to popup a dialog box and after 5 seconds, I want the page to redirects to google.com . Therefore, I need to have a delay function but settimeout() doesnt work. here is the code. How can I delay 5 seconds before redirect...
By the way, I am using someone's javascript code to display which works perfectly.

```
<a href="javascript:showDialog('Error','You have encountered a critical error.','error',10);setTimeout(window.location.href ='http://google.com', 5000);">Error</a>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` works, it's just not used correctly. Try something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
function clickHandle() {
   showDialog('Error','You have encountered a critical error.','error',10);
   setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href ='http://google.com';
   }, 5000);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="clickHandle()">Error</a>
```

The first argument of `setTimeout` is code to be executed (for example string to be evaluated) but better practice is to avoid `eval` and use a callback instead (like in my example).

It's not so good idea to put your click handler directly in the HTML. I suggest you to use `onclick` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your redirect in a function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href ='http://google.com';
}, 5000);
```